# Why do I have 200 MB GPU usage even when I only created 1 byte data?

Tags: cuda

I run the following code in RTX 3060 and RTX 3080 Ti. And by using `nvidia-smi`, I found the real GPU usage is 105MB and 247MB for RTX 3060 and RTX 3080 Ti separately. Yet I only have 1 byte data in GPU. Why is this? And Why does the basic GPU usage differ?

```
// compiled with nvcc -O3 show_basic_gpu_usage.cu -o show_basic_gpu_usage
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){


  int run_count = 100;

  int * ddd;
  cudaMalloc(&ddd, 1);      // 1 byte
  
  for (int i = 0; i < run_count; i++){
  
    sleep(1);
    printf("%d\n" , i);

  }
}
```

Comment: CUDA has **overhead**.  In order to establish a CUDA context on a GPU, so that CUDA is usable on that GPU, a large amount of memory is required. This is necessary just so you can run a CUDA code on that GPU, before you even allocate any memory. You can think of it as the operating system for the GPU, and it requires GPU memory to run, regardless of what your code is doing.  This question almost certainly has a duplicate here on the `cuda` SO tag.  And different GPUs will have different requirements, because of differing architecture and memory size.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did the search, yet without any useful info

Comment: Perhaps the needed memory is 2.7MB per SM plus an additional 30 MB? The RTX 3060 has 28 SMs, the RTX 3080Ti has 80 SMs. Each SM may run 1536 threads at a time, which have to be managed and which also in turn can use (thread) local memory, which resides in the global memory. Or with Dynamic Parallelism kernels can in turn start other kernels. For this feature or for debugging purposes the state of the SMs can be frozen and swapped out. That is all guessing, but giving you some ideas, where the memory requirement could come from. Actually a few hundert megabytes are not much, all considering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running a CUDA program on a GPU requires something like an operating system, not unlike the way running a typical program you might write on the host system CPU also requires an operating system.

In CUDA this GPU operating system is often referred to as the "CUDA runtime" or perhaps the "CUDA driver".  The CUDA runtime does all sorts of administration and housekeeping for the GPU, and it requires (both CPU memory and) GPU memory to do that.  Some of this requirement is independent of what your code actually does, some of it may vary based on what your code does.

The memory requirement for this "overhead" can vary based on a number of factors:

- exact CUDA version and GPU driver version you are using
- the GPU type/architecture
- the host operating system
- the total amount of GPU memory
- which kernels and libraries your code links to or loads
- whether or not multiple GPUs are visible to the CUDA runtime
- (related) whether or not other consumers are using GPU memory, such as a display driver
- and probably other factors

Hundreds of megabytes utilization per GPU for this overhead is common.  This overhead is in addition to whatever your program may allocate.  It's also common to see variation from one GPU type to another.  There isn't any way to exactly predict the amount of overhead that is used, because of the variety of influencing factors.